# Optimal way of finding all unused options from a long list using SailsJS/MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, waterline

I'm building a new API and database for a website and mobile app for schools. Because the app is for very young children who aren't fully literate yet, it uses a single login for schools and then allows students to login by choosing their teacher's icon and then their own icon rather than typing in a username or searching for their name.

To accommodate this, we have a collection of about 1200 kid-friendly icons so as to ensure that there's no overlap where one student has the same icon as another.

The problem is whenever a new student is created or a teacher wants to change a student's icon, we have to eliminate the option of selecting any icon that is already being used by another student at that school.

My first inclination for solving the problem is to link my school table to a separate "availableIcons" table where each row starts out with the full list of possible icons, and each time a student is added, the icon is removed from from the list of available icons, and vice versa for deleted students.

This would prevent the server from having to do the work of looking at all the currently used icons and comparing them against the full list of icons, which sounds like it could be pretty slow, especially with some of our schools having around 500 students.

My concern with this approach is to store the full list of icons, even as numeric keys, seems like it would take up quite a bit of space. By my calculations, it'd be something like 2-4mb per school. This isn't a huge deal, but if there was a way to do it efficiently without having to store the full list for each school, I would much prefer that.

This is all using SailsJS/MongoDB/waterline.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Available icons is derived data. I would prefer not to store it in database.

My approach:

1. Fetch all icons
2. Fetch all used icons for specific school and teacher
3. Take difference of these 2 collections. Consider [`_.difference`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#difference)

1200 icons is not a big number to handle in memory.